# Limit MySQL Results to One From Each "Group"

Tags: mysql, select

Suppose we have a table like the one below.

```
Id | Name | Group
-----------------
1  | John | 1
2  | Zayn | 2
3  | Four | 2
4  | Ben_ | 3
5  | Joe_ | 2
6  | Anna | 1
```

The query below will select all of them.

```
SELECT `Name` FROM `Table` WHERE 1;
```

How would I select only one person from each group? Who it is doesn't really matter, as long as there's only one name from group 1 and one name from group 2 etc.

The `GROUP BY` clause isn't fit for this (according to my error console) because I am selecting non aggregated values, which makes sense.

The `DISTINCT` clause isn't great here either, since I don't want to select the "Group" and definitely not group by their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is not important the resulting name You can anawy leverage some  group functions eg with max or min..

leverage the group functions

```
  select max(name) from your_table 
  group by Group;
```

otherwise you can use subquery

```
select name from your_table 
where Id in (select min(Id) from your_table group by Group);
```

Comment: It should select one `Name` from each `Group`, returning something like `John, Zayn and Ben_`.

Comment: John is the max form group 1, Zayn the max form group 2, and Ben the max for group 3... seems right to me..

Comment: You're right, it does work. I've created an SQL fiddle to test it out. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c272c/3)